# Using Pathlib to search for specific folder

Tags: python, os.walk, pathlib

I am trying to find a specific folder holding a bunch of fits files. The current code I have is

```
redpath = os.path.realpath('.')         
thispath = os.path.realpath(redpath)         
thispath = os.path.realpath(thispath+'/../../../..')
p = Path(thispath)
userinput = 'n'
while (userinput == 'n'):
    text_file = next(p.glob('**/*.fits'))
    print("Is this the correct file path?")
    print(text_file)
    SearchedFiles = []
    SearchedFiles.append(text_file)
    userinput = input("y or n")
    if (userinput == 'n') :
        while(text_file in SearchedFiles) :
            p = Path(thispath)
            text_file = next(p.glob('**/*.fits'))
```

So if pathlib finds the wrong file fist, the user will say so and supposedly the code will then go through and search again until it finds another file with fits folders. I am getting stuck in an infinite loop because it only goes down one path.

Comment: Is the objective to just find a file with matches an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do.
However, it's no wonder you're getting stuck in a loop: by re-initializing `p.glob()` you're starting all over again every time!

`p.glob()` is actually a generator object, which means it will keep track of its progress by itself. You may just use it the way it was meant to be used: by just iterating over it.

So, for instance, you might be better served by the following:

```
redpath = os.path.realpath('.')         
thispath = os.path.realpath(redpath)         
thispath = os.path.realpath(thispath+'/../../../..')
p = Path(thispath)
chosen = None
for text_file in p.glob('**/*.fits'):
    print("Is this the correct file path?")
    print(text_file)
    userinput = input("y or n")
    if userinput == 'y':
        chosen = text_file
        break
if chosen:
    print ("You chose: " + str(chosen))
```

Comment: Thank you! If the user inputs a no, how would one skip the next 20 instead of going one by one?

Comment: You may want to add a `skip` variable, initialize it to `0`, then set it to `20` in the `else` case. Then you can add something like:
`if skip > 0:
    skip-=1
    continue`
at the beginning of your `for` loop.
(the above is definitely not readable, I don't think I can properly format code in a comment, sorry about that)